# installing opencv2.1 on ubuntu gives error

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I have ubuntu 11.10 on my machine and I want to install Opencv2.1. I downloaded cmake, and in the release folder of Opencv2.1 I wrote 'make' in terminal window and until 38% opencv was installing correctly. However at 38% at cxcore it gave many errors about syntax of some hpp files and stopped installing.
First error was this:

cxcore.hpp:177:13: error: 'ptrdiff_t' does not name a type

and the rest of the errors are similar to this.
I really want 2.1 version, so I would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be related to this bug report:

[Bug #791527 in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opencv/+bug/791527)

There the solution is to add an `#include <stddef.h>` to `opencv/cxcore.hpp`

Comment: I was able to solve a similar problem with OpenCV 2.2 in ubuntu by adding that #include <stddef.h> trick in the following file: OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp